# Set numpy array elements to zero for each row's smallest 2 elements

Tags: python, numpy

For example

```
E = 
array([[ 10.        ,   2.38761596,   7.00090613,   4.51495754],
       [  2.38761596,  10.        ,   2.80035826,   1.        ],
       [  7.00090613,   2.80035826,  10.        ,   5.95109207],
       [  4.51495754,   1.        ,   5.95109207,  10.        ]])
```

The indices for **smallest 2 for each row can be get from argsort** :

```
IndexSortE = np.argsort(E)
smallest2 = IndexSortE[:,0:2]
smallest2
array([[1, 3],
       [3, 0],
       [1, 3],
       [1, 0]])
```

**Now how do I get E0 like this ?? :**

```
E0 = 
array([[ 10.        ,   0.00000000,   7.00090613,   0.00000000],
       [  0.00000000,  10.        ,   2.80035826,   0.00000000],
       [  7.00090613,   0.00000000,  10.        ,   0.00000000],
       [  0.00000000,   0.00000000,   5.95109207,  10.        ]])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create another array of row indices; then take advantage of [*advanced indexing*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to modify the corresponding values:

```
E[np.arange(E.shape[0])[:,None], smallest2] = 0

E
#array([[ 10.        ,   0.        ,   7.00090613,   0.        ],
#       [  0.        ,  10.        ,   2.80035826,   0.        ],
#       [  7.00090613,   0.        ,  10.        ,   0.        ],
#       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   5.95109207,  10.        ]])
```

---

To add some explanations, use `np.broadcast_arrays` to see how these indices are broadcasted:

```
np.broadcast_arrays(np.arange(E.shape[0])[:,None], smallest2)

# [array([[0, 0],
#         [1, 1],
#         [2, 2],
#         [3, 3]]), array([[1, 3],
#         [3, 0],
#         [1, 3],
#         [1, 0]])]
```

gives a length two list, the first one gives row indices while the second one gives column indices. Now according to advanced indexing rules, this pair will position elements at

```
(0, 1), (0, 3), 
(1, 3), (1, 0),
...
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks... looks that  [:,None] is the trick... I tried np.arange(E.shape[0]), smallest2] = 0 previously but it give error msg

Comment: Yes. Because the column index is 2d arrays, add a new axis to the row index to make sure they broadcast properly.

Comment: Great advice. I just tried E[   np.arange(E.shape[0])[:,np.newaxis]    ,    smallestB    ] =0 and it also worked.

Comment: `None` and `np.newaxis` are equivalent here. `np.newaxis is None`; `reshape(-1,1)` should work as well. The base line is transform the row indices into a 2d array so that it conforms to the column indices which is also a 2d array.